# is there any call back or response from docusign once document is signed by all signer?

Tags: docusignapi

I am using docusign rest api and sending single document to multiple user using routingOrder attribute. is there any call back function or handler from docusing so that i can check document is signed by all signer?

Answer (score 0):

There can be. DocuSign Connect is the webhook service that allows DS to ping your application when specific events happen.

A high level overview is available on the DocuSign blog: https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-adding-webhooks-application/

Technical documentation is available in the Developer Center: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/connect

Connect can either be configured at the account level, or on individual envelopes using the EventNotification parameter: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/status-and-events#eventnotification-webhooks